# textview and progress bar not updating while syncing mysql to sqlite

Tags: android, textview, retrofit, android-livedata, android-progressbar

While i try to sync data from mysql to sqlite via rest api using retrofit2 library, i am not able to update the live percentage of the sync status

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
Retrofit retrofit;
Baseurl bs;
List<Voterdata> voterslist;
TextView downloadstatus;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bs=new Baseurl();
    retrofit =new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(bs.getBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    downloadstatus=findViewById(R.id.tvdownloadstatus);
    progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressbarvotersdata);
}
```

the retrofit code is divided into two part the onresponse and offline sync

```
public void syncvoterdata(View V){
    downloadstatus.setText("Fetching from server");//is being displayed
    Api_voterdata api=retrofit.create(Api_voterdata.class);
    Call<List<Voterdata>> call=api.voterdata();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Voterdata>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Voterdata>> call, Response<List<Voterdata>> response) {
            voterslist=new ArrayList<>(response.body());
            downloadstatus.setText("fetch completed starting sync with local storage total records:-"+voterslist.size());
            //no change in display
            synctake(voterslist);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Voterdata>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

the sync to sqlite being here

```
public void synctake(List<Voterdata> data){
int totalrecords=data.size();
Log.d("no of rows", String.valueOf(data.size()));// working in logcat
internaldatabase db=new internaldatabase(MainActivity.this);
//both components are not getting updated here
downloadstatus.setText("saved "+0+" of "+totalrecords);
progressBar.setMax(totalrecords);
progressBar.setProgress(0);
progressBar.animate();
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
    db.Syncdata(data.get(i));
    downloadstatus.setText("saved "+i+" of "+totalrecords);
    Log.d("status","saved "+i+" of "+totalrecords);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        progressBar.setProgress(i,true);
    }
}
db.close();
```

}

only after the sqlite sync task is completed the both textview and progress bar is shown to 100 there is no inbetween changes

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do the computation on the main ui thread. Which means your UI is blocked until the loading is done and only updates afterwards.

The ProgressBar you can animate by means of a [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator)

To have such an effect on the text is little more tricky but doable with an [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator)

Answer (score 0):

It actually inside a retrofit2 so it was running on background thread the runmainuithread solved the issue